# Conditional Loading of CSS files based on test condition in JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, yepnope

I'm looking for the best approach to conditionally load some files based on a specific set of conditions.

I have three CSS files and two javascript files which I'm currently loading like so:

```
<link href="core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="add_regular.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="add_retina.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-plugin.min.js"></script>
```

As is evident the fourth file is JQuery and the fifth is my JQuery plugin. Inside the JQuery plugin are a series of functions that are like tests e.g. `isMobile`, `isRetina`, `isPhone`, etc. However, let's focus on `isRetina`.

What I am trying to accomplish is as follows:

1. Load JQuery and my JQuery Plugin first
2. Use `isRetina` function inside my JQuery plugin to check whether the device has a retina display
3. Load `core.min.css`
4. Load `add_regular.min.css` if not Retina display, or load `add_retina.min.css` if Retina display

Currently I'm loading all three CSS files and I wouldn't want to do that because I've got a bunch of other CSS files and I want to load them as my JQuery plugin determines which one is best as per my above example. For example, I might have a `phone.min.css` that I would want to load after I do another test using my plugin's `isPhone` function.

I'm considering using `YepNope` and doing something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yepnope.min.js"></script>
<script>
yepnope([{
    load: ['jquery.min.js', 'jquery-plugin.min.js'],
    test : $.myplugin.isRetina(),
    yep  : ['core.min.css', 'add_retina.min.css'],
    nope : ['core.min.css', 'add_regular.min.css'],
    complete : function(){
       //my jquery plugin constructor here
       $(selector).myplugin(options);
    }
}]);
</script>
```

However, even if the above approach is the correct one, I am not sure how to implement `document.ready`, as my plugin's constructor needs to run only when the DOM is ready.

I would like some ideas on how I can pull this off using `YepNope` or any other solution.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just going over the JQuery Docs for `.ready()`, and apparently `$(function(){});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {});` (I'm not sure how I'm just discovering this #ScratchingMyHead).

I also saw this being used in a `YepNope` Tutorial on NetTuts+: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/easy-script-loading-with-yepnope-js/.

So I guess my earlier code becoming what you see below should solve the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yepnope.min.js"></script>
<script>
yepnope([{
    load: ['jquery.min.js', 'jquery-plugin.min.js', 'core.min.css'],
    test : $.myplugin.isRetina(),
    yep  : 'add_retina.min.css',
    nope : 'add_regular.min.css',
    complete : function(){
       //my jquery plugin constructor added to JQuery DOM Ready Stack
       $(function(){
           $(selector).myplugin(options);
       });           
    }
}]);
</script>
```

I will test this out and remove this if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to implement `document.ready`, as my plugin's constructor needs to run only when the DOM is ready.

There are two relevant events

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // code runs when document+resources have finished loading
});
```

and

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // code runs when document has finished parsing, but before resources loaded
});
```

If you wait for either of these events before importing *jQuery*, I'm not sure what effect it will have on *jQuery's* inbuilt `$(document).ready` / similar.

That said, you do have the option of checking [`document.readyState === 'complete'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState) before attaching listeners, to see if you should invoke straight away.

Comment: Yeah, I'm keen on finding some way to leverage JQuery's own `document.ready` feature

Comment: @ObinwanneHill once _jQuery_ is loaded in you can use it as normal. I was just saying I don't know how it gets affected if it's loaded in after those events have already fired.

Comment: Ok. Did you mean to wrap the `YepNope` code with these event listeners?!

Comment: @ObinwanneHill I thought your problem was you didn't know how to wait for the document to be ready? I'm not sure how you wanted to use it. Most likely you only require it in the `complete` function.

Comment: Ok, no that wasn't my issue, as my question states I was trying to find a way to get the plugin constructor to run when the DOM was ready.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but this should work.

Include this by default:

```
<link href="core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-plugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    yepnope([{
        load: ['jquery.min.js', 'jquery-plugin.min.js'],
        test : $.myplugin.isRetina(),
        yep  : ['core.min.css', 'add_retina.min.css'],
        nope : ['core.min.css', 'add_regular.min.css'],
        complete : function(){
           //my jquery plugin constructor here
           $(selector).myplugin(options);
           //Remove the mask here.
        }
    }]);
    // Feel free to call ready() here
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // whatever you want here
    });
</script>
```

Then you can call `ready()` adding your specific logic according to the output of your tests.  This way `ready` will only fire once the above has loaded and executed.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works or not, but it seems to defeat the purpose of using `YepNope` i.e. asynchronous conditional loading, as well as the performance improvement?!

Comment: @ObinwanneHill Sorry I think I misunderstood original question, have edited above.

Comment: It's ok. You don't have `.ready` in your code though?! Thanks a lot for this, I seem to have stumbled on a solution using the functional equivalent of `.ready` i.e. `$(function(){})`.